# Uniform convergence problem for sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sin(nx)}n$ converges uniformly on $[a, 2\pi - a]$ for $0<a<2\pi$

Actually, I know $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\sin(nx)}n$ converges (by using Dirichlet test).

However, it is difficult for me to prove converge "uniformly".

How can I prove this?

Do I have to use Weierstrass M-test?

Then how?

Comment: Dirichlet's test can actually prove not only a mere pointwise convergence, but also uniform convergence!

Comment: And if you want to avoid a direct reference to this theorem, you may just take summation by parts and apply Weierstrass $M$-test.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The Dirichlet test says that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k}\right|
\le\sup_{m\ge n}\left|\sum_{k=n}^m\sin(kx)\right|\frac1n\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k=n}^m\sin(kx)\right|
&=\left|\mathrm{Im}\left(\frac{e^{i(m+1)x}-e^{inx}}{e^{ix}-1}\right)\right|\\
&\le\frac1{|\sin(x/2)|}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$